# Concatenating existing values within the same array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

Here's an example of an array I'm working with:

```
arr = [ "id1", "name1", "id2", "name2", "id3", "name3" ]
```

I want to change it into a new array that looks like:

```
new_arr = [ "id1: name1", "id2: name2", "id3: name3" ]
```

My attempt:

```
ids = arr.select.with_index { |_, i| i.even? }
names = arr.select.with_index { |_, i| i.odd? }
new_arr = ids.map { |i| i + ": " +  names[ids.index(i)] }
```

Is there a better or more expressive way of doing this (potentially in a one-liner)?

Comment: Are the ids unique?

Comment: Yes, IDs are unique and it always comes in that ID, name pattern for the array.

Comment: Then you may be interested in using a hash, `arr.each_slice(2).to_h #=> {"id1"=>"name1", "id2"=>"name2", "id3"=>"name3"}` for easy access to values using the usual hash[key] notation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the requirement for application is to format the data like `new_arr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `each_slice` and string interpolation.

```
arr.each_slice(2).map { |(a, b)| "#{a}: #{b}" }
#=> ["id1: name1", "id2: name2", "id3: name3"]
```

Richard Hamilton`s comment made me think about the performance of the different solutions:

```
require 'benchmark'

arr = [ "id1", "name1", "id2", "name2", "id3", "name3" ]
slices = arr.each_slice(2)

n = 1_000_000

Benchmark.bmbm(15) do |x|
  x.report("hashified     :") { n.times do; Hash[*arr].map { |e| e.join ': ' }    ; end }
  x.report("concatenation :") { n.times do; slices.map { |a| a[0] + ": " + a[1] } ; end }
  x.report("array join    :") { n.times do; slices.map { |a| a.join(': ') }       ; end }
  x.report("interpolated  :") { n.times do; slices.map { |(a, b)| "#{a}: #{b}" }  ; end }
end

# Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------------
# hashified     :   3.520000   0.030000   3.550000 (  3.561024)
# concatenation :   2.300000   0.010000   2.310000 (  2.315952)
# array join    :   3.020000   0.010000   3.030000 (  3.032235)
# interpolated  :   1.950000   0.000000   1.950000 (  1.954937)
# ----------------------------------------- total: 10.840000sec
# 
#                       user     system      total        real
# hashified     :   3.430000   0.040000   3.470000 (  3.473274)
# concatenation :   2.320000   0.010000   2.330000 (  2.332920)
# array join    :   3.070000   0.010000   3.080000 (  3.081937)
# interpolated  :   1.950000   0.000000   1.950000 (  1.956998)
```

Comment: All `each_slice` derivatives have the same glitch: the won’t fail on odd amount of elements.

Comment: Not *all* derivates: My version would raise an error on an odd number of elements, because of the `(a, b)` part.

Comment: As a sidenote, for a Ruby benchmark you should also measure the number of created short-living objects, since in a production system Ruby's abysmal garbage collection often have a worse performance impact than runtime.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something when I tried using your code with odd amount of elements `arr = ["id1", "name1", "id2", "name2", "id3", "name3", "id4"]` it didn't raise any error. Instead it returned `["id1: name1", "id2: name2", "id3: name3", "id4: "]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html)'s [`each_slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) method to get an enumeration of 2-element arrays from your `arr`. You can then simply `join` these elements:

```
arr.each_slice(2).map{|a| a.join(': ')}
```

What happens here is the `each_slice` returns an [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html) which yields the 2-element arrays. Since `Enumerator`s also are `Enumerable`, you can just use `map` to change these 2-element arrays and [`join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-join) them to a String.

Comment: I didn't think about using `join`. That makes this more efficient than my answer

Answer (score 2):

`each_slice` is silly :)

```
Hash[ "id1", "name1", "id2", "name2", "id3", "name3" ].
  map { |e| e.join ': ' }
#⇒ [ "id1: name1", "id2: name2", "id3: name3" ]
```

Comment: This breaks once you have duplicate "ids".

Comment: @HolgerJust that is why I think this solution is in fact better.

Comment: You think your solution is better because it breaks on edge cases? That... is an uncommon opinion.

Comment: @HolgerJust ok, I can explain. These `id`s (please, read the name of the variable _very carefully_) live in the real world. The behavior of this method is determined, it is idempotent and it produces the result, that has no _oups_. The result always has a single `id`’s value. It’s not still proven to be correct, but at least it is single. Also, this method throws an exception on odd number of arguments.

Comment: Oh, funny, “I don’t understand the consequences” comment got upvoted.

Comment: I think I found a sillier solution: `arr.partition.with_index { |e,i| i.even? }.transpose.map { |ar| ar.join(': ') }`?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 at least it won’t succeed on odd amount of items, therefore it is already better that `each_slice`.

Comment: (1) It's not idempotent (that's a different thing) (2) Nowhere does OP say that the odd values are unique, which is not required for the array. It might be assumed but is not guaranteed. Depending on the actual data OP gets, your method might thus produce subtly incorrect results by just omitting some data elements from the result.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `each_slice`:

```
arr.each_slice(2).entries.map { |ar| ar.join(': ') }                    
#=> ["id1: name1", "id2: name2", "id3: name3"]
```

Comment: `entries` is superfluous here. See other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `each_slice` for this

```
arr.each_slice(2).map { |a| a[0] + ": " + a[1] }
=> ["id1: name1", "id2: name2", "id3: name3"]
```

Comment: `a.first` and `a.last` may be used here too.